# Render PDF from byte[] with specific filename using blazor .net 8

Tags: pdf, blazor, filenames, .net-8.0, content-disposition

I've created a new project using visual studio templates to describe my problem.

New project information template information:
Blazor Web App.
Framework: .NET 8.0 (Long Term Support)
Authentication type: None
Configure for HTTPS: true
Interactive render mode: Server
Interactivity location: Per page/component
Include sample pages: true
Do not use top-level statements: true

I add a PDF (HiMom.pdf) to my wwwroot folder.

I write this code in Home.razor:

```cs
@page "/"
@inject IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>
<object type="application/pdf" data="@($"data:application/pdf;base64,{base64PdfString}")" style="position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;" width="100%" height="100%"/>
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public HttpContext? HttpContext { get; set; }
    private string? base64PdfString = null;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (HttpContext != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Response.Headers.Append("content-disposition", "inline; filename=MyCustomName.pdf");
        }
        var pdfFilePath = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "HiMom.pdf");
        var pdfBlob = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdfFilePath);
        base64PdfString = Convert.ToBase64String(pdfBlob);
    }
}
```

In Home.razor I render a PDF.
In my real application I read a PDF as a byte array from the database.
I simulate this by converting a local PDF file to a byte array.

When I start the application the browser opens the PDF. 
This is all good.

However, when the browser opens the PDF I can choose to save the PDF.
This opens a dialog where the filename is always download.pdf.

I want to be able to set this filename from my code. How can I do that?

As you can see I tried doing it using HttpContext and setting content-disposition header.

[full code](https://github.com/bobbin054/BlazorRenderPDFFromByteArray.git)